# Pipe output of executable in Powershell to file?

Tags: xml, powershell, xsd

I'm trying to validate a set of xml files against xsd's in bulk with xmllint and pipe the output to a file, I have a map of folders to xsd's and I'm looping over them and it works in terminal, but when trying to output the results to a file `./validate.ps1 > output.txt`, I only get the explicit echo's outputting. I've tried piping the command to Out-Default, that does nothing, I've tried piping the error-out to null and such, doesn't work, I've tried using cmd /c, that does nothing.

```
$schemas.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    echo $schema
    $schema = $_
    $location = $schemas.Item($schema)
    Get-ChildItem $dev\$location -Filter *.xml |
    Foreach-Object {
        $restype = $_.FullName
        &$xmllint --noout --schema $dev\XMLSchema\$schema $restype # The line not outputting
    }
}
```

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You're suppressing the output with `--noout` I guess.

Comment: No, that just suppresses outputting the entire xml file alongside the output of whether the validation fails, which still shows up.

Comment: `--noout` looks like it suppresses returning of the XML tree. If you want to output something you need to tell it, ie with `--valid`.

Comment: Oh, xmllint prints to stderr so you need to redirect it in order for PS to capture the output by adding `2>&1` in the command line.

Comment: Well that kind of worked, but now every entry is followed by a remoteException Error, can I separate those out? They don't show up in the terminal output usually.

Comment: Barring fixing the actual error, you could check output ie `... 2>&1 | Where { $_ -is [String] } | Out-File output.txt`

Comment: That caused nothing to output, thanks though

Comment: This will probably help you: https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right/